# Set model variable from activeTextField with Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm have difficulty setting a variable in my model from an activeTestField in Yii.
Here is my view:

```
echo CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'text_field', array('id'=>'test'));
echo CHtml::submitButton('Query');
```

My model:

```
class QueryForm extends CFormModel
{   
    public $text_field;
}
```

My controller:

```
public function actionQuery()
{
    $model=new QueryForm;
    echo $model->text_field;
}
```

I've been searching for answers on google but I've had difficulty finidng answers to complete beginner questions such as this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead you should do this

```
if (isset($_POST['textField']) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['textField'];
    echo $model->text_field;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the text field by giving it a name in the array of html options:

```
array('name'=>'textField', ...);
```

and then using post in my controller:

```
if (isset($_POST['textField']) {
    $model->text_field = $_POST['textField'];
}
```